# Making an association the only ID for a column

Tags: sequelize.js

I want Users in my *database* to have a list of `tags`. I'd like the Tags table to be two columns:

1. User ID -`userId`
2. Tag Name -`tag`

I currently have tried by making User`.hasMany(Tags, { primaryKey: true, foreginKey: 'userId' });`
But I end up with an "ID" column on top of all of the other columns. I'd like for "UserID/TagName" to be a unique correlation (meaning there can **only be once** instance of a *User* and *tag*)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest options is to add a new migration with Unique constraint on userId & tag as below,

```
module.exports = {
  up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    const sql = 'ALTER TABLE Tags ADD CONSTRAINT user_id_tag UNIQUE(userId, tag)';

    return queryInterface.sequelize.query(sql, { type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW,
      raw: true,
    });
  },
  down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    const sql = 'ALTER TABLE Tags DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS user_id_tag';

    return queryInterface.sequelize.query(sql, { type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW,
      raw: true,
    });
  },
};
```